# Linux Kernel Device Tree Parsing

Tags: linux-kernel, device-tree

I am beginner to Device Tree. 
I know that after a few architecture-specific initialization, start_kernel function will be called.
Could someone provide some material on how dtb is parsed..?
First fdt function called..?

Comment: *"First fdt function called..?"* -- Try looking at **of_core_init()**.  Use a cross reference such as [bootlin.com](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source) to trace that function back to **arch_call_rest_init()** and **start_kernel()**.

Answer (score 0):

Below video tutorial from bootlin is an excellent starting point to understand device tree.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m_NyYEBxfn8